# About expected value of ratio of Uniform random variables

Tags: expected-value

Let $X_{1},X_{2},X_{3}$ be  independent uniform random variables over (0,1). Find
$E[\frac{X_{1}+X_{2}+X_{3}}{X_{2}}]$.

Is there any idea for this?

Comment: Usually you should write your try, and underline the passage is not clear to you

Comment: I don't think this question should have been closed off, because I don't think it is off topic. The question reduces to finding $E[\frac{X}{Y}]$ when $X$ and $Y$ are independent standard Uniforms. And the answer to that is the integral does not converge, and so the expectation does not exist.

Comment: @wolfies do you think this is not self-study (as in http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info)?

Comment: No I don't. I don't think this is a question from a textbook or course. I think someone just needs some help solving a problem ... which has turned out not to have the answer they were expecting (if you can excuse the pun)

Comment: I agree that this is an interesting question as wolfies notes.  Self study is a difficult issue.  When an OP possess a question that looks like it is demanding an answer the OP should reword the question or explain in comment why it is not self study.  I think that sometimes people jump the gun by putting a question on hold too early.  I prefer to suggest in comment that the self study tag should probably be added.  In this case I do think the expectation can be simplified to a constant plus E[X/Y] where X and Y are independent uniforms.

Comment: By independence if the expectation exists it would be 1+ E(X) E(1/Y) and the question becomes does E{1/Y] exist when Y is U{0, 1}.

Comment: @wolfies it is on hold because it doesn't meet the site standards for `self-study` questions which it appears to be.. This Q was [posted to math.SE yesterday](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2071872/about-expected-mean-of-uniform-dist#comment4255205_2071872) (and closed there for the same reason -- for not meeting the site standard for homework-style questions). I also made a very similar comment to your point about E(X/Y) there, but the OP did not attempt to use the hint to improve their question there, choosing to repost the same question just as they originally posted it.

Comment: @Glen_b, you are undoubtedly right, but usually we let new users know via one of the standard texts ("please add the self-study tag") to given them a chance of fixing the question. Alessandro certainly aimed to do that, but that may not have been clear to the new user.

Comment: @ChristophHanck Perhaps Juho's link to it (above) is sufficient.